# C++ printing out file names in ascending order

Tags: c++, file, sorting

I am using the following code to iterate through files in the directory. All the files in this directory are numbered, each with a unique number.

The code below successfully prints out all the files in the directory however not in ascending order. It comes out completely random and one file is duplicated.

I can't find another way of printing out the files or printing them in ascending order. I really need to print them in ascending order and then later open them in ascending order. Any help is appreciated.

`DIR *dpdf;
    struct dirent *epdf;`

```
dpdf = opendir("/data/files");
if (dpdf != NULL){
   while (epdf = readdir(dpdf)){
      printf("%s\n",epdf->d_name);
         // std::out << epdf->d_name << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the file names into a vector as you read them.

When you've read all of them, use `std::sort` to sort the array.

Then process the sorted file names as you see fit.

Comment: And be sure to use `std::unique_ptr` with `::closedir` to prevent leaks when `std::vector::emplace_back` throws.

Comment: Awesome, I shall try this.