# C++ How to put the names of files within a directory into a vector?

Tags: c++, boost, vector

I simply need to put all the files (or file names?) within a directory into a vector so that I can sort them and open them in order.

I literally have no idea how to do this since this my first encounter with C++. I have tried boost::filesystem but I am having no success as this is quite unfamiliar to me. Please help!

I've actually found a method I think will work however I am now struggling with adding a linker to the command line but I think if I ask about that here it'll exceed the scope of the original question.

Comment: Try to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283546/cboostfilesystem-how-can-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-folder-in-which-the-fi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

taken from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345378/c-printing-out-file-names-in-ascending-order):

```
std::vector<std::string> filenames;
dpdf = opendir("/data/files");
if (dpdf != NULL) {
   while (epdf = readdir(dpdf)) {
      filenames.push_back(std::string(epdf->d_name));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
fs::directory_iterator b("path of directory"), e;
std::vector<fs::path> paths(b, e);
```

This includes sub-directories (but not their contents).  If you want to exclude sub-directories, you can use `fs::is_directory` on a path to check if it is a directory.  If you want to include the contents of the sub-directories, then you can use a `recursive_directory_iterator` instead of a `directory_iterator`.

Comment: With c++17 you no longer need boost and use std::filesystem

Comment: +1. For novices: _1)_ Using `std::filesystem` is the same, i.e. in this example just changing the `boost::filesystem` to `std::filesystem` would work. _2)_ default constructed `directory_iterator` equals "end iterator", thus the `e` in the 2nd line is end iterator.